# How can I get the original type of a Mock after the Mock has been cast to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, moq, autofixture

I have a `ServiceCollection`, and I want to make a method where I can pass in a set of parameters, and have the `ServiceCollection` return those services when the matching type is requested.  I am using [Autofixture](https://autofixture.github.io/docs/quick-start/#) to create my services.  When I call `fixture.Create<IMyService>`, it'll return a `Mock<IMyService>`.  For example

```
public static IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(params object[] services)
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    
    foreach (object service in services)
    {
       serviceCollection.AddTransient(factory => service);
    }

    return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

And then I want to use it like this

```
[Fact]
public void TestSomething()
{
   // This causes myFirstService to be of type of type IMyFirstService,
   // but have a value of type Mock<IMyFirstService> (same for
   // mySecondService)
   var fixture = new Fixture();
   IMyFirstService myFirstService = fixture.Create<IMyFirstService>();
   IMySecondService mySecondService = fixture.Create<IMySecondService>();

   var serviceProvider = CreateServiceProvider(myFirstService, mySecondService);

   // I want the returned objects to be myFirstService and mySecondService
   // that I created above
   var resolvedFirstService = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyFirstService>();
   var resolvedSecondService = serviceProvider.GetService<IMySecondService>();
}
```

The problem is that `myFirstService` and `mySecondService` are not returned, because the services are cast to an `object` when `CreateServiceProvider` is called, so they get registered with the `ServiceCollection` as type `object` instead of the correct interface type.  I tried using `serviceProvider.GetService(service.GetType(), factory => service)` but the problem is that `service.GetType()` returns `Castle.Proxies.IMyFirstServiceProxy`.

I know I can make this work by doing the code below instead, but I want it to work by having the `CreateServiceProvider` method register those services.

```
[Fact]
public void TestSomething()
{
   var fixture = new Fixture();
   IMyFirstService myFirstService = fixture.Create<IMyFirstService>();
   IMySecondService mySecondService = fixture.Create<IMySecondService>();

   var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
   serviceCollection.AddTransient(factory => myFirstService);
   serviceCollection.AddTransient(factory => mySecondService);
   var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

   var resolvedFirstService = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyFirstService>();
   var resolvedSecondService = serviceProvider.GetService<IMySecondService>();
}
```

Comment: Make sure to post [mre] of the code - "I know I can make this work by doing the code below instead" - the code posted as "working" behave exactly the same as non-working one (returning nulls for services as expected).

Comment: (which is because type of `var myFirstService` is `Mock<IXxxx>` rather than `IXxxx`)

Comment: Do you want to do `var serviceProvider = CreateServiceProvider(myFirstService.Object, mySecondService.Object);` where you say `.Object` on each `Mock<>`? And if for some reason you want the mock back from the object, try: `var recoveredMock = Mock.Get(resolvedFirstService);` etc.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, I was trying to simplify the example by not mentioning that I was using Autofixture, but your comment made me realize that I actually changed the functionality in my example code.  I updated my question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thank you for the suggestion.  What you said would have worked, but I realized that I had posted incorrect code by leaving out the fact that I'm using Autofixture.  So when I create my Mocks, they are actually of type `IMyService` rather than `Mock<IMyService>`, even though the value is actually a `Mock`.  I updated my question to have the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know an easy way to achieve that but if you are adamant on going this way you can go with quite brittle path of the reflection and messing with implementation details:

```
static IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(params object[] services)
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

    foreach (object service in services)
    {
        // relying on the mocked object implementing IMocked:
        var mocked = service as IMocked; 

        // using internal property:
        var mockedType = typeof(Mock).GetProperty("MockedType", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .GetValue(mocked.Mock) as Type;

        serviceCollection.AddTransient(mockedType, _ => service);
    }

    return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

But again this can be quite brittle so I recommend to reconsider the approach and use `Type`'s as parameters:

```
static IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(params Type[] services)
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    var context = new SpecimenContext(fixture);
    foreach (var serviceType in services)
    {
        var instance = fixture.Create(serviceType, context);
        serviceCollection.AddTransient(serviceType, _ => instance);
    }

    return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

With call like:

```
var serviceProvider = CreateServiceProvider(typeof(IMyFirstService), typeof(IMySecondService));
```

Comment: Thank you.  That second block of code does exactly what I want.